# Stop animation looping back to initial position in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I've made an animation on an Image object in my Unity game. When the animation has finished it animates back to its original position! I'd like to stop this from happening. I've tried Googling and searching here on SO but can't see any solutions so far! My animated object has an `Animation` and `Animator` components attached to it. The `Animation` component has an array of 3 animations. I only want to ensure one of them does not loop back to its default/original position.....

Here is a screenshot of the animation components attached the gameobject:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suppose in the animation sequence the last frame is the same as the first frame? This is what usually happens and restores the animation to the original position. Try removing the "loop" tick of the animation as well as check the first and last frame.

Comment: OMG you solved the issue! The last frame was the same as the first frame! Duh! How do you preview the animation on an object before starting the game? I could preview the animation when making it but can't figure out how to to go back and re-play the animation after :S also, how can I make the animation go to another once it has finished? Would this be something I control within Animator?

Comment: I've had a look in the Animator and set a transition between objects but that doesn't seem to do anything.... am I going about this the right way? How would you transition to another animation once one has finished?

Comment: @Lloyd Click on the object that is already in your game hierarchy, if it has an animation press ctrl + 6 and it will open a new window. You will see the animation there and you can press the play button (in that new window) to see the animation playing in the scene. To go to another animation you will have to use animation transitions in the Animator.

Comment: @Lloyd You will need to use keys/parameters in order to activate the transition. I suggest watching a video on the subject, try something like Unity animation transitions, there are plenty of informative tutorials out there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've done ctrl+6, the animation window opens but no animation within it. When I click the game object it displays the animation and animator controller within it though. The animation plays in the game too. It's strange I can't preview the animation again with the method you said?

Comment: @Lloyd Yes, the gameobject should be clicked on if you want to see the associated animations/animator component with that object, I thought I mentioned that part about clicking but it doesn't matter actually, most importantly you now know how to preview it :)

Comment: I actually can't preview the animation attached to the object at all :( I can only preview it when clicking to play the game! :/

Comment: @Lloyd Click on the gameobject that holds the animation (very important!, if you even click on the parent of the object (and it has no animation) you will not be able to preview it.) So when you click on it, you press ctrl + 6, a new window pops up. There is a dropdown menu to the top left of the window that lets you pick the animation you want to see, you also see its frames, etc. There is also a play button in that same window (not the unity's scene play button). When you click it, if you can see the object in the scene then you will also see the animation playing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've clicked the actual object itself (the one that's being animated), then ctrl+6, the animation window shows but blank! No frames within it, dropdown menu and play buttons greyed out.... just completely blank :/

Comment: @Lloyd Have you attached the Animator component with the controller to the object? If not, I suppose it's time to open some tutorial and check out how the transitions happen, after that you will know the basics of it and having an Animator with different animations in it you will be able to select the various animations from the dropdown menu and preview them.

Comment: You're right I do need to read up a bit more about animations/transitions. But I have attached the animator to the object... I'll update my original post with a screenshot of the components attached to the animated object

Comment: @Lloyd So, if you will be using the transitions, you will only need the Animator component without the Animation one and you will setup all animations (that you have created beforehand) inside the controller of the Animator. Transitions, parameters, etc. After that you will control the parameters with your code so that the transitions can get triggered. If you then click on the correct object (I repeat - watch out if it's a nested gameobject, make sure you click on the object with the animator) you will be able to scroll through animations and preview them. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it just now. You must unchecked to Root Transform Position(XZ) / Bake Into Pose, from inside your animation.

[image]